# How to reload the content of the page from the drawer navigator

Tags: android, react-native, navigation

I created a nested drawer navigator within the stack navigator by using react native. The page structure is like:

```
-StackNavigator:  
  -DrawerNavigator:   
     -HomePage,   
     -ListPage,       
  -DetailPage
```

When user click a menu item in the drawer, we launch the ListPage by using this.props.navigation.navigate('ListPage') with a param. This is working fine if user in HomePage. The ListPage can load the content correctly by fetching the data within componentDidMount

But the problem here is if the current page is ListPage, user click another menu item in the drawer, the list page is not refreshing with new content. I guess react navigation will ignore the navigate action if the current page is the page we want to navigate to. So my question here is how can we force to refresh the page for this situation. Many thanks

Comment: I resolve this issue in 'react-navigation:2.X' but not proper worked in 'react-navigation:3:x'